# React Redux Slice Reducer makes Component State readonlu

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an app which has multiple components in it, one of which is a simple todo list. When a user updates a value in the list, or toggles the task as complete, I want the redux store updated. In my `toggleComplete` function in my component, if I don't try and call the reducer, I am able to update a task's `complete` flag with the opposit to the current state. However when I call the reducer as part of my `saveToDos` function, this causes the app to error in my line `task['complete'] = !task['complete']`

configSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const configSlice = createSlice({
    name:'config',
    initialState: {
        weatherLocation:'',
        todos:{
            mainGoal: {
                desc:'',
                complete: false
            },
            priorities_1: {
                    desc:'',
                    complete: false
                },
            priorities_2: {
                    desc:'',
                    complete: false
                },
            priorities_3: {
                    desc:'',
                    complete: false
                },
            other_todos: []
        },
        links:[]
    },
    reducers: {
        updateToDos: (state, action) => {
            state.todos = action.payload    
            },
        updateLinks: (state, action) => { 
            state.links = action.payload
        },
        updateLocation: (state, action) => {
            state.weatherLocation = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export const { updateToDos, updateLinks, updateLocation} = configSlice.actions
export default configSlice.reducer
```

ToDo.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {Auth} from 'aws-amplify';
import {setUser, setAuthorizationToken} from '../auth/authSlice';
import { updateToDos } from "../config/configSlice";
// import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import './todo.css'

class Todo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            edit:false,
            mainGoal: {
                desc:'',
                complete: false
            },
            priorities_1: {
                    desc:'',
                    complete: false
                },
            priorities_2: {
                    desc:'',
                    complete: false
                },
            priorities_3: {
                    desc:'',
                    complete: false
                },
            other_todos: []
        }
        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this)
        this.saveToDos = this.saveToDos.bind(this)
        this.toggleComplete = this.toggleComplete.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        <<Snip>>

        let todos = this.props.todos
        this.setState({todos})
    }

    saveToDos = () => {
        console.log('saving')
        let {edit, ...todos} = this.state
        this.props.updateToDos(todos)
    }

   <<Snip>>

    toggleComplete = e => {
        console.log(e.target)
        let task = this.state[e.target.name]

        console.log(task)
        task['complete'] = !task['complete']

        console.log(task)

        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: task
        }, () => {this.saveToDos()})
    }

    render() {
        return(
        <div className="todo-panel">
                
                <<SNIP>>
 
                <div className="mt-3">
                    <h6>Today's Main Goal</h6>
                    <div className="input-group">
                        <input type="text" className={`form-control offset-1 ${this.state.mainGoal.complete && 'strikethrough'}`} 
                            value={this.state.mainGoal.desc}
                            readOnly={!this.state.edit}
                            name='mainGoal'
                            onChange={this.handleInput}
                            onBlur = {this.saveToDos}
                        />
                        <button 
                            type="button" 
                            className="btn btn-outline-success"
                            name='mainGoal'
                            onClick={this.toggleComplete}
                        >Complete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <<SNIP OTHER JSX>>

            </div>
        )
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        currentUser: state.auth,
        todos: state.config.todos
    };
  }
  
  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    { 
        setUser,
        updateToDos
    }
  )(Todo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're directly modifying the state object in the toggleComplete function, which can cause unexpected behavior when using Redux.

To fix this, you should create a copy of the task object before updating its properties. Then, update the component state using the new object. You can use the spread operator to make a shallow copy of the object:

```
toggleComplete = e => {
    console.log(e.target);
    let task = this.state[e.target.name];
    
    console.log(task);
    let updatedTask = { ...task, complete: !task['complete'] }; // Make a shallow copy of the task object and update the 'complete' property

    console.log(updatedTask);

    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: updatedTask
    }, () => { this.saveToDos() });
}
```

This change ensures that you're not directly mutating the state object and should prevent the error from occurring when calling the reducer in your saveToDos function.

Comment: Amazing - thanks - I can't mark as the answer yet - you got there too quickly!